# Clean any output of a linux console

Tags: linux, console, gstreamer

I have a linux installation without X. When I launch a third-part application (i.e. gstreamer) it draws on a portion of the screen, let the users see through the external areas.

I want to "clear" the console so it appears black. Of course the clear command won't work because you still see the prompt.

Might you recommend any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable which contains the output displayed by the prompt is named `PS1`. You can empty this variable when needed.

Don't forget to keep a 'backup' of the value in order to be able to set it back to its old value